# Windows Batch: How to create and use generated code

Tags: batch-file

I need help creating a for loop that generates the following example code below depending on the `%count%` variable and then execute it:

So if %count%=4 it would output the following:

```
IF %M%==1 set %variable%
IF %M%==2 set %variable%
IF %M%==3 set %variable%
IF %M%==4 EXIT
```

If %count%= 7 output would be:

```
IF %M%==1 set %variable%
IF %M%==2 set %variable%
IF %M%==3 set %variable%
IF %M%==4 set %variable%
IF %M%==5 set %variable%
IF %M%==6 set %variable%
IF %M%==7 EXIT
```

I was thinking of echoing the for loop into a new batch file and then execute it, not sure if thats the best approach?

Ex:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
echo IF %M%==%count% set %variable% > new.bat
)

call new.bat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why must the code be dynamically generated and executed?

You can get the same end result with the following simple static code:

```
set /a count2=count-1
for /l %%N in (1 1 %count2%) do if %M% equ %%N set %variable%
if %M% equ %count% exit
```

If you know that M is numeric, then:

```
if %M% geq 1 if %M% lss %count% set %variable%
if %M% equ %count% exit
```

Comment: EDIT - The logic was off a bit for the first solution: all fixed via an extra computed count2

Answer (score 0):

To call it directly you can use:

`cmd /Q /C echo Command1 & echo Command2 & pause` or `cmd /Q /C %variable%`

You'll of course want to be mindful of quotation marks this way though. To get all of the options use `cmd /?`, but most of the basic ones are:

```
CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
/A      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be ANSI
/U      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be
        Unicode
/T:fg   Sets the foreground/background colors (see COLOR /? for more info)
/E:ON   Enable command extensions (see below)
/E:OFF  Disable command extensions (see below)
/F:ON   Enable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/F:OFF  Disable file and directory name completion characters (see below)
/V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
        delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
        variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
        at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
        loop.
/V:OFF  Disable delayed environment expansion.
```